# Вывод полученных данных из foreach php

Tags: php

Не могу понять как можно извлечь полученные данные в `foreach` (возможна не точная интерпретация):

```
require "api_vk.php";
$ms = new message_send();

$query = "fate/apocrypha, fate (series), love live!";
$qq = explode(", ", $query);

$link = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "****", "****");
foreach($qq as $value){
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tags_copyright WHERE `first` LIKE '%{$value}%'");
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        if($result['last'] != ""){
            echo $result['last'].", ";
            //Выводит: #Fate_Series, #Love_Live,
            $ms->send("{$result['last']}, ", "1414", "4dd8818d772ec9e89e62c661");}}}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Мне нужно что бы этот элемент исполнялся один раз:

```
$ms->send("Вселенные: {$result['last']}, ", "1414", "4dd8818d772ec9e89e62c661");
```

Сейчас фактически все работает, но из-за того что элемент

```
$ms->send...
```

выполняется несколько раз он отсылает несколько сообщений.

> 12:00 > #Fate_Series,
>
> 12:00 > #Love_Live,

Нужно что бы сообщение было отправлено один раз, что бы получилось:

> 12:00 > #Fate_Series, #Love_Live,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

require "api_vk.php";
$ms = new message_send();

$query = "fate/apocrypha, fate (series), love live!";
$qq = explode(", ", $query);
$text = '';
$link = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "****", "****");
foreach ($qq as $value) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tags_copyright WHERE `first` LIKE '%{$value}%'");
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        if ($result['last'] != "") {
            $text .= $result['last'] . ", ";
            //Выводит: #Fate_Series, #Love_Live,

        }
    }
}
$ms->send("$text, ", "1414", "4dd8818d772ec9e89e62c661");
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: А зачем там в конце две запятых?

Comment: эм, этот вопрос к автору уже

Comment: а если посмотреть внимательно?

Comment: я не собираюсь чистить код за автором, я показал как сделать то что ему нужно. дальше думаю разберется

Comment: а для чего вообще цикл `while`, если проще сделать с помощью `array_column`, а потом `implode`

Comment: @Solo_777, благодарю. Все работает =)